# Why if I declare a string array without any length specified, it still works? Both with or without dynamic allocation

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char mystring[] = {0};

    scanf("%[^\n]s", mystring);

    printf("%s\n%d\n", mystring, strlen(mystring));

}
```

Output:

```
$ ./"dyn_mem" 
pffwemfmwefefkfnefkfkwfkfkwfkwfkfkwkfkfpwefkpfwfkffnefkfekfefkefekfekwfkefekfmekfmkfmefmew
pffwemfmwefefkfnefkfkwfkfkwfkwfkfkwkfkfpwefkpfwfkffnefkfekfefkefekfekwfkefekfmekfmkfmefmew
90
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This gives `Segmentation fault: 11` but is ***somehow*** able to print even a very long string. How can it be possible? What does `char mystring[] = {0};` do? Does it something like dynamically allocate the string ? I can't explain to myself why this works.

**Also, if I do that with *malloc* or *calloc*, it works without any error.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char *mystring = calloc(2, sizeof(char));

    scanf("%10[^\n]s", mystring);

    printf("\nValue: %s\nAvailable space: %d\nAllocated space: %d\n", mystring, 2*sizeof(char), sizeof(char)*strlen(mystring));

    free(mystring);

}
```

Output:

```
$ ./"dyn_mem" 
laaaaaaaaaaa

Value: laaaaaaaaa
Available space: 2
Allocated space: 10
```

How can it be possible to contain such a long string if I only allocated 2 bytes?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is just that - undefined. Who knows what memory comes after that properly allocated for your character array. Maybe you'll get lucky, and it won't affect anything else in your code; or maybe it will.

Comment: "it works" -- no it does not! you were simply unlucky (but smart to ask in SO): the way **it does not work** appears to be the way you expected it to work.

Comment: @pmg He wasn't lucky, he was unlucky. When you have a serious bug like this case of undefined behaviour, it's much better if it crashes immediately and you realise you need to fix it.

Comment: unlucky, that's what I said @gnasher729

Answer (score 0):

Neither piece of code is valid.

In the first case, the number of elements of `mystring` is determined by its initializer.  Since you initialize it with `{ 0 }` the size of the array is 1 element.  The `scanf` then writes past the end of the array bounds invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes the program to crash.

In the second case you allocate space for a 2 element array, and `scanf` again writes past the end of allocated memory.  This also invokes undefined behavior, but in this case the program appears to work properly.

Just because the program *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Comment: Thanks for answer. At this point I really want to know how in the first case it worked and in the second, too. How is this possible? Does scanf "force" to write in contiguous memory and "extend" the length/size of the array? How could this be possible?

Comment: @Mnkisd You're writing to memory that you shouldn't be.  Once you do that, all bets are off.

Comment: The second variant would most likely crash when you free() the memory. Or as soon as you do it in any more complex situation, because your memory allocation system is probably messed up at this point.

Comment: @Mnkisd The questions is backwards. Ask why it's impossible in Java. Because there are mechanisms that makes it impossible, such as boundary control. Those mechanisms does not exist in C.